# Getting the max for a set of rows in R

Tags: r

So I have a set of Time series data which is made up of 1 min intervals for a whole month. I am looking to get some results from this data.

- The highest utilized one hour.
- The lowest utilized one hour.
- The same for day.

Can't add a sample of my data until I get 10 posts.

I have already copied it to another dataset so I don't alter the other one.

```
busiestmin <- rdata6
dput(MyData)
busiestmin[ busiestmin$Utilized == max(busiestmin$Utilized) , ] 
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  Entitled Utilized            datetime
  <dbl>    <dbl>              <dttm>
    1     2.73 2016-12-18 02:10:00
busiestmin[ busiestmin$Utilized == min(busiestmin$Utilized) , ]
# A tibble: 22 × 3
   Entitled Utilized            datetime
    <dbl>    <dbl>              <dttm>
      0        0 2016-12-11 03:03:00
      0        0 2016-12-11 03:04:00
      0        0 2016-12-11 03:05:00
      0        0 2016-12-11 03:06:00
      0        0 2016-12-11 03:07:00
      0        0 2016-12-11 03:08:00
      0        0 2016-12-11 03:09:00
      0        0 2016-12-11 03:10:00
      0        0 2016-12-11 03:11:00
      0        0 2016-12-11 03:12:00
```

# ... with 12 more rows
As you can see above I know how to get the min and max of one line but would like to get it to show a set of 60 lines (1 Hour) and 1440 line (1 day).

Not sure if the link to the sample data set will work?

```
dput (MyData) 
 Entitled   Utilized    datetime
  1     1.04        12/3/2016 0:01
  1     1.04        12/3/2016 0:02
  1     1.04        12/3/2016 0:03
  1     1.20        12/3/2016 0:04
  1     1.21        12/3/2016 0:05
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on the example

Comment: It won't let me copy and paste it in from r studio?? Any ideas?

Comment: You _can_ add your data in the form that is best for SO - as text.  Please use `dput(MyData)` to get a text format for your data that you can just paste into your question.   If there is too much data,  you might try  `dput(head(MyData, 20))`

Comment: okay sure thanks I shall try

Comment: Please update it in your post

Comment: Not working?  So it's column 1 I have Entitled which is all numbered 1, 2nd column is the Utilized amount which varies for each min, and the 3rd column I have the datetime which I have formatted to for example 2016-12-03 00:01:00.

Comment: It is not the dput output you updated

Comment: I would recommend you round `datetime` variable to the nearest hour and compute `min()` and `max()` `by` `datetime`. Let me know if you need me to write this out for you.

Comment: Figured out  how to add it sorry about before it's my first ever post on SO.

Comment: Thank you @JustGettinStarted I shall see if anyone else has any other way so I don't really want to round my data, or it won't be as precise as I want it to be.

Comment: If you could write it out that would be great thanks. @JustGettinStarted

Comment: yeah you would round to a new variable so you're not over writing anything. But you basically want to sum up all the 1 minute values within every hour to get the numbers per hour (and also day) and then calculate the min and max of these hourly and daily totals. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that is one way I can do it, but I would like to be able to see a list of the 60 1 min intervals for the most Utilized hour and 1440 1 min intervals for day. If you are able to write that out that would be great thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that using lubridate is going to help you out here a lot.

This is how I read in your example data:

```r
library(readr)
example_data <- read_csv("Entitled, Utilized, datetime\n
                                 1,     1.04, 2016-12-03 00:01:00\n
                                 1,     1.04, 2016-12-03 00:02:00\n
                                 1,     1.04, 2016-12-03 00:03:00\n
                                 1,     1.20, 2016-12-03 00:04:00\n
                                 1,     1.21, 2016-12-03 00:05:00\n
                                 1,     1.05, 2016-12-03 00:06:00\n
                                 1,     1.05, 2016-12-03 00:07:00\n
                                 1,     1.05, 2016-12-03 00:08:00\n
                                 1,     1.43, 2016-12-03 00:09:00\n
                                 1,     1.60, 2016-12-03 00:10:00")
```

Since your example data is all from the same hour and day, we aren't going to be able to see differences between hours and day, but this should work for what you are talking about. The first thing we need to do is set up a new variable that keeps track of which day (or hour) each time stamp came from. You can use `floor_date` from lubridate for that.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

example_data %>% 
    mutate(FloorDate = floor_date(datetime, unit = "1 day"))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    Entitled Utilized            datetime  FloorDate
#>       <int>    <dbl>              <dttm>     <dttm>
#> 1         1     1.04 2016-12-03 00:01:00 2016-12-03
#> 2         1     1.04 2016-12-03 00:02:00 2016-12-03
#> 3         1     1.04 2016-12-03 00:03:00 2016-12-03
#> 4         1     1.20 2016-12-03 00:04:00 2016-12-03
#> 5         1     1.21 2016-12-03 00:05:00 2016-12-03
#> 6         1     1.05 2016-12-03 00:06:00 2016-12-03
#> 7         1     1.05 2016-12-03 00:07:00 2016-12-03
#> 8         1     1.05 2016-12-03 00:08:00 2016-12-03
#> 9         1     1.43 2016-12-03 00:09:00 2016-12-03
#> 10        1     1.60 2016-12-03 00:10:00 2016-12-03
```

If your data has more than one day or hour in it, you will see those in the new column we just created. You can use `unit = "1 hour"` if you want to find the max/min for each hour. Now we can use `group_by` and `summarize` to find the max and min for each day.

```r
example_data %>% 
    mutate(FloorDate = floor_date(datetime, unit = "1 day")) %>%
    group_by(FloorDate) %>%
    summarise(MaxUtilized = max(Utilized),
              MinUtilized = min(Utilized))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>    FloorDate MaxUtilized MinUtilized
#>       <dttm>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 2016-12-03         1.6        1.04
```

If your real data has multiple days in it, your result here will have rows for each day, with the max and min for each.